# Check if a character (not string) is lowercase, uppercase, alphanumeric?

Tags: emacs, character, elisp, uppercase

What is the idiomatic and most effecient way to check if a single character in Elisp is lowercase, uppercase, alphanumeric, digit, whitespace, or any other similar character category? For example [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) has string methods like `isdigit()`, but converting a character (which is just a number) to a string in Elisp to check if it belongs to a certain case or category seems like a wrong approach:

```
(string-match-p "[[:lower:]]" (char-to-string ?a))
```

Comment: `char-syntax` should be pretty efficient, but it's not wrapped as nicely as you'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard way, but I think it is not hard to roll your own:

```
(defun wordp (c) (= ?w (char-syntax c)))
(defun lowercasep (c) (and (wordp c) (= c (downcase c))))
(defun uppercasep (c) (and (wordp c) (= c (upcase c))))
(defun whitespacep (c) (= 32 (char-syntax c)))
```

See also `cl-digit-char-p` in `cl-lib.el`.

Answer (score 3):

Use **[get-char-code-property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Properties.html#index-get_002dchar_002dcode_002dproperty-3931)** to look up the Unicode general category of the character. A lower-case letter, for example, gives a value of `"Ll"`:

```
(string= "Ll" (get-char-code-property ?a 'general-category))
     ⇒ t
```

An upper-case letter gives `"Lu"`, and a decimal number `"Nd"`.  See the [full list of values](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values).